# How to use Google Cloud Endpoints with Volley?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, android-volley

With Google Cloud Endpoints, you still need to manage async tasks, parallel network requests, compatibility on Froyo, etc.

Is there any way to use Volley with Cloud Endpoints requests?

Comment: did you get the answer to your above question?

Answer (score 1):

You can use volley but it overlaps with most of the features provided by the Endpoints generated libraries.

Your main issue will be including OAuth headers in your requests, after that you can basically call the endpoints as you would any other URL and serialize the results yourself using volley.

The documentation on how to include the OAuth is [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/consume_android#making_authenticated_calls).